# codeIgniter error when getting the post

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Hello I have an jQuery sending by post info to a codeIgniter function:

```
$("#anular").click(function() {      
       var param = {
               code: '123',
               cache: false
       };         
       var post = $.post($('#myForm').attr ('action'), param, 
        function (data) {
            alert (data);
        }, 'json'); 
 });
```

And I have from my codeIgniter side:

```
 function fcancel() { 
          $info = $this->input->post('code');
          echo $info;
 }
```

The problem is that $info doesn't receive the data just null. I can't find the problem. I initialized the url and form helpers of codeIgniter, and in some other cases was working but there it doesn't. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a problem on the client side...i just made a test with your sample code ind the values are passed just right `Form Data: code:123
cache:false` ...then the problem is server side

Comment: Can you dump only `$this->input->post()` without any parameters and see is there any postdata?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the 'json' I changed into 'text' and started working.

Cheers.

Comment: For jQuery to accept a JSON as a response type you will have to set the headers correctly on the PHP side. You could try adding `header("Content-Type: application/json");` to your PHP code before the `echo` statement and also, make sure what you print out is valid json format `echo json_encode(array($info));` and see what you get back...